# I get an invalid query error when I add WHERE Name =

Tags: c#, sql, winapi, directory, wmi

```
public static void Command(string vCommand, string machineName, string username, string password)
            {
                ManagementScope Scope = null;
                ConnectionOptions ConnOptions = null;
                ObjectQuery ObjQuery = null;
                ManagementObjectSearcher ObjSearcher = null;
                try
                {
                    ConnOptions = new ConnectionOptions();
                    ConnOptions.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
                    ConnOptions.EnablePrivileges = true;
                    //local machine
                    if (machineName.ToUpper() == Environment.MachineName.ToUpper())
                        Scope = new ManagementScope(@"\ROOT\CIMV2", ConnOptions);
                    else
                    {
                        //remote machine
                        ConnOptions.Username = username;
                        ConnOptions.Password = password;
                        Scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\" + machineName + @"\ROOT\CIMV2", ConnOptions);
                    }
                    Scope.Connect();

                    ObjQuery = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Directory WHERE Name = 'c:\\0stuff'");
                    ObjSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(Scope, ObjQuery);

                    foreach (ManagementObject obj in ObjSearcher.Get()) //ERROR HAPPEN HERE
                    {
                       //code here
                    }

                    if (ObjSearcher != null)
                    {
                        ObjSearcher.Dispose();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
        }
```

If I use only "ObjQuery = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Directory");", I get no problem at all.

But as soon as I try to use "WHERE Name = X", I get an "invalid query" error.

I don't know what is wrong. (and before someone ask, yes c:\0stuff exist).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a verbatim string literal `@"..."` to prevent the backslash being treated as an escape sequence in C#:

```
@"SELECT * FROM Win32_Directory WHERE Name = 'c:\\0stuff'"
```

Without the `@` the query that is actually sent will look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Win32_Directory WHERE Name = 'c:\0stuff'
```

Notice that the backslash is no longer properly escaped.

Comment: It works! Thanks alot. How the hell was I supposed to know that I had to double backslash for both C# AND SQL >_<   
That is something I wont forget (I hope)