# I get an "Invalid Name" error when I try to use "CopyEx"

Tags: c#, winapi, copy, wmi

Regarding [my previous problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621218/i-get-an-invalid-query-error-when-i-add-where-name) that is now fixed, I got another problem with the //code here part :/

```
foreach (ManagementObject obj in ObjSearcher.Get())
{  
    ManagementBaseObject inputArgs = obj.GetMethodParameters("CopyEx");
    inputArgs["FileName"] = "\\c:\\1stuff";
    inputArgs["Recursive"] = true;
    ManagementBaseObject outParams = obj.InvokeMethod("CopyEx", inputArgs, null);
    uint ret = (uint)(outParams.Properties["ReturnValue"].Value);
}
```

I keep getting a returnvalue of 9, which is "Invalid Name".
I have no idea what got an invalid name nor how to fix it. Both folder exist.

Comment: What's the purpose of the leading backslash ("\\") in your file name?  That's not valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a leading backslash in your file name.  Try removing it.  I'm not aware of any file paths that have the format you're using.

Comment: Removing the leading \ gives an error 10, which is "Invalid Level"

Comment: I think you have to specify the path like this: `\\MACHINENAME\root\cimv2:Win32_Directory.Name="<your path>"`

Comment: (and use `\\.\` for the local machine)

Comment: What's the entire resulting string that you're using?  Inside of the `Name=""`, you have to make sure you escape (which might mean double-escaping) your string.

Comment: inputArgs["FileName"] = @"\\"+machineName+@"\root\cimv2:Win32_Directory.Name='c:\\1stuff'";

Comment: Also tried inputArgs["FileName"] = @"\\"+machineName+@"\root\cimv2:Win32_Directory.Name='c:\1stuff'";

Comment: According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389324(VS.85).aspx, error 10 means "The object specified already exists."  Perhaps just @"c:\1stuff" works fine but there's already a file/directory there blocking the copy.

Comment: Damn, it is that! Changed name and it created a new one. Now, I gotta find the command to override an already existing folder... Or that I will have to do a Delete before a Copy